# FreeTextBox control not changing its .Text property when client writes

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, web-services, web-applications

Basically I'm using the FreeTextBox control from www.freetextbox.com/.
My problem is that whenever I type text into the control on the client side the .Text property does not change.
What could possibly be the issue here? I can easily change the .Text property programatically but I can't access the text typed into the control by the client.

I've been messing with this issue for 3 hours now and would definitely appreciate if someone could help me out!

Btw I'm using ASP.NET and C#

Comment: Can you show some code of where you are accessing the `text`? And are you adding this programmatically or through the designer?

Comment: @Darren
Sure:
Here I'm adding it in the aspx file:
<code>
<FTB:FreeTextBox ID="FreeTextBox1" runat="Server" Focus="true" SupportFolder="FreeTextBox/"

                                    JavaScriptLocation="ExternalFile" ButtonImagesLocation="ExternalFile" ToolbarImagesLocation="ExternalFile"
DesignModeCss="designmode.css" ButtonSet="Office2000" />
</code>

Here I'm trying to access the text in C#:
<code>
string txt = FreeTextBox1.Text;
</code>

Comment: added an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Text` is definitely the correct property to get the entered text.

I wonder if you have anything in your `page_load` that is setting the text?

If so, put this inside

`if (!isPostBack) {}` for C# or `If (Not isPostBack) Then` for VB - to prevent the text that is entered on the page from being overridden by the `page_load` (which will fire before your button click event)

Alternatively, if you're able to, then consider using [CK Editor](http://ckeditor.com/) (ASP.Net download is [HERE](http://ckeditor.com/download).

I recently changed from FTB to CK Editor because FTB ceased working correctly in the most recent FireFox and Chrome browsers - FTB is no longer being supported and has become outdated and full of little issues.

Since changing the editor on systems a couple of weeks ago, to CK Editor, we have had zero issues with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was the onpage load that screwed me over here. I also changed to ckeditor and it works great. I really appreciate your assistance!